# Nested Repeaters - access value from parent row in Footer

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a case of nested repeaters where a child repeater is nested in the `ItemTemplate` of a parent repeater. The DataSource of the parent is a `Dictionary<String, List<XYZ>>`.
In the `ItemDataBound` of the parent Repeater I am using the full code:

```
     protected void rptParent_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
     {
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
         {
      if (e.Item.DataItem is KeyValuePair<String, List<Object>>)
            {
                pair = (KeyValuePair<String, List<XYZ>>)e.Item.DataItem;
            }

            Repeater childRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("rptChild") as Repeater;

            //bind the child repeater.
            childRepeater.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(childRepeater_ItemDataBound);
            childRepeater.DataSource = pair.Value;
            childRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void childRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
        {
    //Access the Parent row's Key value

  }
    }
```

There are 2 questions:

1. Can I use a hidden field while binding the parent and set it to the Key value and then retrieve the hidden field value in the child?
2. Will the order of the events firing be as follows:

a. `Parent_ItemDataBound` for Row 1 of `Dictionary<Key, List<XYZ>>`

i. `Child_ItemDataBound` **for each** child row of Row 1 of parent repeater

ii. `Child_ItemDataBound` for Footer of child repeater

b. `Parent_ItemDataBound` for Row 2 of `Dictionary<Key, List<XYZ>>`

i. `Child_ItemDataBound` **for each** child row of Row 2 of parent repeater

ii. `Child_ItemDataBound` for Footer of child repeater

and so on. In other words, will the `Parent_ItemDataBound` be followed by `Child_ItemDataBound` events for each child row - with the cycle repeating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the answers to your question:

1. Yes, you can access parent repeater item control

   var hfID = e.Item.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.FindControl("hfID") as HiddenField;
2. the order is correct.

Hope that helps